# chef ohai does not fetch any os attributes

Tags: windows, azure, chef-infra, wmi, ohai-gem

I am running command `ohai -l debug` on Windows server 2016 which should output server attributes.

On one VM it returns empty arrays on most important attributes:

```
"kernel": {

},
"memory": {
  "swap": {

  }
},
"network": {
  "interfaces": {

  }
},
"counters": {
  "network": {

  }
},
"os": "windows",
"os_version": null,
"platform": "windows",
"platform_version": null,
"platform_family": "windows",
"dmi": {

},
"virtualization": {
  "systems": {

  }
},
```

Virtual machine is Windows in Microsoft Azure cloud.
[Azure instance metadata API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows) returns necessary values. Others Azure windows servers works fine, the problem is only with one server.

I am not very familiar with ruby. However, I assume that ohai code responsible for kernel data retrieval is [here](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/kernel.rb): `collect_data(:windows)`.
So I wanted to diagnose WMI with [WMI Diag tool](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmidiag-2-2-is-here/ba-p/375642), but this tool seems not available anymore.

It is kind of dead-end to me.
Is there any way to check why ohai does not return attributes? And if it is related to WMI, to debug it or see output in Powershell?

I tried these versions of ohai:

- 15.16.4
- 16.4.41
- 16.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Data was not collected due to failure in WMI service in Azure.

Problem was fixed after WMI repository has been rebuilt.

More info here: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/21413-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.